# What is the encoding of the body of Gmail message? How to decode it?

Tags: python, encoding, gmail-api

I am using the Python API for Gmail. I am querying for some messages and retrieving them correctly, but the body of the messages looks like total nonsense, even when the MIME type it's said to be `text/plain` or `text/html`.

I have been searching all over the API docs, but they keep saying it's a string, when it obviously must be some encoding... I thought it could be `base64` encoding, but trying to decode it with Python `base64` gives me `TypeError: Incorrect padding`, so either it's not `base64` or I'm decoding badly.

I'd love to provide a good example, but since I'm handling sensitive information I'll have to obfuscate it a bit...

```
{
 "payload": {
  "mimeType": "multipart/mixed",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   ...
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 0
  },
  "parts": [
   {
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1140b160adc309053bd7ec57"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
    "size": 0
    },
    "parts": [
     {
      "partId": "0.0",
      "mimeType": "text/plain",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
       },
       {
        "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
        "value": "quoted-printable"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
           "size": 4067,
           "data": "LS0tLS0tLS0tLSBGb3J3YXJkZWQgbWVzc2FnZSAtLS0tLS0tLS0tDQpGcm9tOiBMaW5rZWRJbiA8am9iLWFwcHNAbGlua2VkaW4uY29tPg0KRGF0ZTogU2F0LCBTZXAgMywgMjAxNiBhdCA5OjMwIEFNDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBBcHBsaWNhdGlvbiBmb3IgU2VuaW9yIEJhY2tlbmQgRGV2ZWxvcG..."
      }
```

The field that I'm talking about is `payload.parts[0].parts[0].body.data`. I have truncated it at a random point, so I doubt is decodable like that, but you get the point... What is that encoding?

Also, wouldn't hurt to know where in the docs they explicitly say its base64 (unless it's the standard encoding for MIME?).

**UPDATE:** So in the end there was some bad luck involved. I have 5 mails like this, and turns out that the first one is malformed, for some unknown reason. After moving on to the other ones, I am able to decode all of them with the suggested approaches in the answers. Thank you all!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is base64.

Your truncated message is:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: LinkedIn <job-apps@linkedin.com>
Date: Sat, Sep 3, 2016 at 9:30 AM
Subject: Application for Senior Backend Develop
```

Here's some sample code:

I had to remove the last 3 characters from your truncated message because I was getting the same padding error as you. You probably have some garbage the message you're trying to decode.

```
import base64

body = "LS0tLS0tLS0tLSBGb3J3YXJkZWQgbWVzc2FnZSAtLS0tLS0tLS0tDQpGcm9tOiBMaW5rZWRJbiA8am9iLWFwcHNAbGlua2VkaW4uY29tPg0KRGF0ZTogU2F0LCBTZXAgMywgMjAxNiBhdCA5OjMwIEFNDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBBcHBsaWNhdGlvbiBmb3IgU2VuaW9yIEJhY2tlbmQgRGV2ZWxv"

result = base64.b64decode(body)

print(result)
```

### UPDATE

Here's a snippet for gettting and decoding the message body. The decoding part was taken from the gMail API documentation:

```
  message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id, format='full').execute()
  msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['payload']['body']['data'].encode('UTF8'))
  mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str) 

  print(msg_str)
```

Reference doc:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#python

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this. Your snippet works for me too, but for some reason the body I'm getting from the request is slightly different than that I have provided (got it from the API console instead of the Python code). I am trying to find out why...

Comment: I just tried the same snippet, just replaced the contents of body with the string I got from the API Explorer. It worked just fine. Can you find a message you don't mind exposing and sharing the body you're trying?

Comment: I cannot find a message with the same structure right now... I'll try to get one when I have more time. For the moment, maybe could you have a look at my comment on @EricDeFriez answer? That's where the issue is I believe...

Comment: I've just checked it. I'll write some sample code using the API to parse my own emails and update my answer accordingly

Comment: Still, the decoding is giving me a mix of normal characters and garbage characters... Any idea why? I tried converting the decoded string to UTF-8 or ASCII but it raises errors. (The original is an HTML).

Comment: A sample: `G��������ѐ�ݥ�Ѡ���̈ <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="13px"> <tbody���]��[OH�Z[�`

Comment: @houcros I've updated my answer with a real snippet and references docs.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You helped me a lot. What I was missing was the `encode('UTF8')` **before** the `urlsafe_b64decode`. I was doing it `after`, and that was why some messages were not possible to b64decode or were still garbaged. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. The use of the `email` library really did the trick for me, as well as the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: @DallaRosa you're the best!

Answer (score 7):

Important distinction, it is **web safe base64** encoded (aka "base64url") .  The docs are not very good on it, the MessagePartBody is best documented here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments

And it says the type is "bytes" (which obviously isn't save to transmit over JSON as-is), but I agree with you, it doesn't clearly specify it's base64url encoded like other "bytes" fields are in the API.

As for padding issues, is it because you're truncating?  If not, check that "len(data) % 4 == 0", if not, it means the API is returning unpadded data, which would be unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for more clarification. I've checked, and the `len(data) % 4 == 0` is `true`, so that is not the issue... But I noticed that the answer that I get from my Python request is slightly different than the one from the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/). The first one is slightly longer than the second one, and it's exactly the same for many characters at the beginning and end... Any idea why this could happen? Maybe is this worth another question?

Comment: About different replies on Python API and API explorer, that was my bad, sorry. You can have a look at my update, but shortly the issue was that one mail was malformed, for some reason...

Comment: This is a very important distinction. I was trying to parse to a byte array in C# and was getting an exception. Switching to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urldecode?view=aspnetcore-5.0 did the trick

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64decode(body).decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's base64. You can use base64.decodestring to read it.
The part of the message that your attached is:  '---------- Forwarded message ----------\r\nFrom: LinkedIn <job-apps@linkedin.com>\r\nDate: Sat, Sep 3, 2016 at 9:30 AM\r\nSubject: Application for Senior Backend Develo'

The incorrect padding error means that you're decoding an incorrect number of characters. You're probably trying to decode a truncated message.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying that but I'm getting `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`. And with `base64.b64decode` I'm getting `TypeError: Incorrect padding`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "LS0tLS0tLS0tLSBGb3J3YXJkZWQgbWVzc2FnZSAtLS0tLS0tLS0tDQpGcm9tOiBMaW5rZWRJbiA8am9iLWFwcHNAbGlua2VkaW4uY29tPg0KRGF0ZTogU2F0LCBTZXAgMywgMjAxNiBhdCA5OjMwIEFNDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBBcHBsaWNhdGlvbiBmb3IgU2VuaW9yIEJhY2tlbmQgRGV2ZWxvcG==".decode('base64')
'---------- Forwarded message ----------\r\nFrom: LinkedIn <job-apps@linkedin.com>\r\nDate: Sat, Sep 3, 2016 at 9:30 AM\r\nSubject: Application for Senior Backend Develop'
```